WordPress "Attachment Fixed" Background Not working Still Scrolling
When image Setg As Fixed it must be fixed when scrolling but it still scrolling. i cleared bowser Cache & change the browsers As well. But it still won't work.
Image resoluion -  Full
Position - Center Center
Attatchment - Fixed
Repeat - Default
Display Size - Default
